# How to show that the $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Consider the sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+3}{3x_n+1}$ where $n \geq 1$ with $0<x_1<1$.

I tried it this way, splitting the terms gives $x_{n+1}-x_n=3(1-x_{n+1}x_n)$.

But that doesn’t seems to be useful. Actually I am trying to find a recurrence relation between $x_{n+1}-x_n$ and $x_n-x_{n-1}$. But don’t know how??

Any other approach??

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Start with figuring out that limit if exists is equal to 1.

Comment: Have you heard of the ratio test? This seems like a good place to start.

Comment: @Vsevolod A. That’s trivial right!! Just taking the limits replacing $x_n’s$ with a single x gives x=1 finally. My question is how to show that the limit exists??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Rewrite as $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8/3}{3x_n+1}$. Now, argue that

- $0 < x_0 < 1 \Longrightarrow 1 < x_1 < 3$
- $1 < x_1 < 3 \Longrightarrow \frac{3}{5} < x_2 < 1$

We see that the possible range shrinks to $(\frac{3}{5},1)$, "closer" to $1$.

Apply this inductively to deduce that $(x_n)\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Ah that’s amazing!! Thanks a lot!! @lisyarus